# kernel dies when loading .mat file with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, kernel, mat-file

I'm trying to load a .mat dataset using scipy but every time I run it the kernel dies and restarts without loading the file.
I tried this using jupyter notebook and spyder and both give the same result the code I used is:

```
    import scipy.io as sio
    mat = sio.loadmat('lateral.mat')
```

can anyone tell me where is th problem?
my OS is windows 8

Comment: Is it just this file?  or any .mat?  We can't help you with the scanty information that you provide.

Comment: Other large files cause the same problem but when I tried smaller and simpler files it returns this error: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: probably the mat file is screwed up.